# making a json object in php that is parsable by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a huge list of things with each of those things broken down into four sub-things. I am easily able to gather them in nested arrays in PHP, but when I use `json_encode` to pass them as a JSON object to my javascript client side, the `JSON.parse()` function always fails because my data is filled with all kinds of entities like `' / \ " & % {} []`

It's a shame there is no constant that you can add to `json_encode` to ensure it's javascript ready.

What characters must I escape or otherwise deal with to ensure I get a javascript parsable object. I was unable to find one. I could easily write a function to handle this if I knew which characters to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem with your approach.
Maybe there is a problem when rendering the data?
Did you try the following to output the json?

```
echo 'var myjs = ' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($obj)) . ';';
```

If you render the json in a different url/endpoint you do not have to encode anything yourself.
However you should make sure your http headers are set correctly

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($obj);
die(0); # thx for requesting my endpoint
```

Comment: I was just passing the nested array as json_encode($array). I will try the htmlspecialcharacters approach. And I like the idea of grabbing the object after page load, I may just do that. It may end up that way anyways. Thanks!

Comment: htmlspecialcharacters didn't work. I just passed it directly as a var as you said without using JSON.parse, and it all worked fine. In the end I built a small php function to create a javascript array of objects and pushed it into the javascript var and it all works great, no worry about special characters at all.